# Receive calls and texts from a mobile modem on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, modem, arm, mobile-broadband, cellular

Other posts on SuperUser about this issue are either too old to be useful, are for a different operating system, or are not exactly what I am looking for.

## Background

I have a Windows 10-on-Arm cellular connected tablet, (Galaxy Book2, SM-W737A) that has a Qualcomm Mobile Broadband Modem installed in it. It uses 3G and 4G LTE perfectly well. My SIM card and data plan supports unlimited everthing. I have been able to use this device and modem to send and receive texts and calls using Ubuntu Linux. However I don't know how to do this on Windows.

## Question

How can I use my Mobile Broadband Modem on Windows-10 to interact with mobile public switched telephone network (PSTN) to send and receive sms/mms via standards like Signaling System 7 (SS7)?

## Evidence

[image: Cellular Settings Screen]

Comment: There is a free app named mysms in the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/mysms-text-from-computer-messaging/9wzdncrfhwdc#activetab=pivot:overviewtab). Try it to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but no. That is an app that allows for "texting" via a helper app on a mobile phone. Essentially a cloud relay service. I'm asking about using my windows tablet as a bare-metal mobile device

Comment: Do you have in *Settings  > Network & Internet > Cellular & SIM*? If this is not helpful, the following Microsoft apps might help: [Microsoft Phone](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-phone/9wzdncrdtbwp?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) and [MobileVoIP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/mobilevoip/9wzdncrfj3n6#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) and [TextNow](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/textnow-unlimited-texts-calls/9n43spjlcxcv#activetab=pivot:overviewtab). Otherwise contact the Support of your carrier.

Comment: Yes, I have that feature. The Windows 10 Desktop tablet can surf the internet using my cellular connection. The "Microsoft Phone" app you provided are only for Windows Phone. As those apps are not found in the Desktop Windows Store. The MobileVoIP is not what I am looking for as it is a VoIP service that I have to sign up for. I'm already paying AT&T for a cellular PSTN enabled sim. This sim when plugged into my Android works as a phone. I would like to perform the same behaviors using my simcard on my tablet. Using my tablet as a bare-metal cellular phone.

Comment: I might be able to side-load the [Microsoft Phone](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-phone/9wzdncrdtbwp?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) app you suggested @harrymc, but I would first have to find a way to download a copy of the app, since I don't have a windows phone, I don't know how I could get a copy of this app.

Comment: What do you have in Cellular & SIM? A screenshot would be useful.

Comment: Sorry, I had already provided a screenshot but failed to tell you.

Comment: That will teach me to scroll up. Try to run the following app: `%windir%\System32\dialer.exe`. Running `dialer` may be enough.

Comment: Did you try `dialer`?

Comment: I have a windows 10 laptop with a sim card and on opening dialer I get a warning msg “Phone dialer was unable to find a telephone device or modem to use to dial voice calls.”

Answer (score 1):

Sierra Skylight can receive and send SMS:
[image: SMS Express]
But no calls.

It is available e.g. from [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/skylight/9mx5c36zwd6x).

Skylight supports at least some Qualcomm chips: my Dell has Qualcomm DW5811e, and it's supported. Actually, Sierra Skylight is available for downloading from Dell's support website as [Connection Manager App](https://dl.dell.com/FOLDER04512042M/5/Connection-Manager-App-for-DW5811E-and-DW5816E_JDW49_WIN_6.0.4686.8202_A06.EXE?uid=6cabafc6-18fc-4009-70f2-295131c798d2&fn=Connection-Manager-App-for-DW5811E-and-DW5816E_JDW49_WIN_6.0.4686.8202_A06.EXE).

I'm not sure whether it supports Qualcomm chip installed in your Samsung Galaxy Book2, but I'd give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Download the "Microsoft Messaging" from the Microsoft Store, you can receive messages

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-messaging/9wzdncrfjbq6#activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill Note that I flagged this answer as low quality, and I now received a notice telling me my flag was denied and not to flag such posts.

Comment: I didn't handle your flag.

Answer (score -3):

I use Modem Partner for sending and receiving SMS and phone calls on Windows, I'm not quite sure if it will work perfectly with your modem, since I use only Huawei E153 and Modem Partner works perfectly with it.

Comment: Thanks but your answer is a way to use a Hauawei cell phone's modem to text via USB. I just have a windows-10 tablet with a cellular modem on its motherboard.